# How to monitor database roundtrips

Tags: .net, sql-server, entity-framework

I have a web application that is using Entity Framework to query a SQL Server database. I would like to be able to know programmatically how many queries (round-trips) were executed on the database. The idea is to log that information to easily detect errors where a relationship was not included and caused lots of round-trips.

Is there a way to achieve this? I don't mind if the solution is specific to SQL Server.

**Note:** I want to monitor the database **programmatically**, therefore tools such as SQL Server Profiler are no use to me. I want to be able to know, at the end of a request and in the code that handles the request, how many queries were executed by that request.

Comment: SQL Server Profiler would be my first thought.  Does it matter if you see requests the databases sees, vs what EF submits?

Comment: Thanks, but I need a programmatic solution that I can include in my code. Please see my edit for more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [provider statistics feature](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7h2ahss8.aspx) of the SQL connection.

Comment: That's very interesting. Do you have any idea how I can use this from Entity Framework? I suppose that I will need to capture the creation and disposal of the connections, but I have no idea how to do it.

Comment: Ok, I found it, I will try to use the ObjectContext.Connection property. I will update the question with my results.

Comment: You can create the connection yourself, if you prefer.

Answer (score 2):

This is my final solution, based on Craig Stuntz suggestion.

```
using(var database = new MyEntities())
{
    SqlConnection sqlConnection = null;

    var entityConnection = _database.Connection as EntityConnection;
    if (entityConnection != null)
    {
        sqlConnection = entityConnection.StoreConnection as SqlConnection;

        // Enable statistics
        sqlConnection.StatisticsEnabled = true;
    }

    // Access the database

    if (sqlConnection != null)
    {
        var statistics = sqlConnection.RetrieveStatistics();
        var selectCount = (long)statistics["SelectCount"];

        // Do something with the statistics
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe use [EFProf](http://efprof.com/)?

Comment: The programmatic access of EFProf seems complex to integrate and not fit to be used in a web application.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of thoughts:

- If you use T4 templates to produce your entity contexts, you can alter the generated code to provide logging information or whatever you want.
- If you connect to your dlls using LinqPad, you can run any methods you want and LinqPad will capture the queries in the SQL tab.

Comment: I am using the default code generator for edmx files. Can I customize it?

Comment: @Antoine Aubry: See this article on how to use a T4 template instead: (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/efdesign/archive/2009/01/22/customizing-entity-classes-with-t4.aspx).  It doesn't change the edmx file, but rather the .cs file that gets generated from the edmx.

Answer (score 0):

I did this the hard way using SQL Server 2008 Profiler, if you set the right filters in profiler you will see only the calls made by EF.

Comment: Thanks, but I need a programmatic solution that I can include in my code. Please see my edit for more details.